# How to target and shorten a long string in bash with "..."

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, string

I'm doing some web development and I am printing out some object data in the console. I want to target one property/field denoted in output as `dataURI: DFASDFKAJELKJDFSADFMLAKFJLSKDJFAJSDFL` which is a super long string, and shorten it then append with ellipses at say 25 characters. Is there a .bashrc script or command for this? I don't want to get ellipses on entire output, just the `dataURI` field.

Comment: Your not telling how your printing that data in the console, but assuming that it's a file, `perl -pe 's/\b(dataURI:\
s*)(\S{11})\S{3,}(\S{11})/$1$2...$3/g'`

Comment: My web application is printing this object from javascript, when certain actions trigger. But I wanted to catch them with bash script rather then change the javascript console.log().

Comment: Or shorter, and doing actually 25 instead of 24 characters: `... input .. | perl -pe 's/\bdataURI:\s*\S{11}\K\S{4,}(?=\S{11})/.../g'`. You can call that from a bash script. Doing string processing in bash is actually not a good idea, so unless you're already having that data in a bash variable, don't get it there with a `while IFS= read -r var; do ...; done` in the 1st place ;-)

Comment: Oh ok I'll trust you then that it's not a good idea then, I'll find a workaround in javascript, thank you!

Comment: FWIW, my first substitution works exactly the same in javascript as in perl: `your_string.replace(/\b(dataURI:\ s*)(\S{11})\S{4,}(\S{11})/g, "$1$2..$3")`

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
printf "%.25s...\n" "dataURI: DFASDFKAJELKJDFSADFMLAKFJLSKDJFAJSDFL"
```

Or you can use parameter expansion:

```
echo "${yourvar:0:25}..."
```

Though with both of these if your string is shorter than 25 characters it'll still include the ellipsis.

Comment: It is printing from web application using javascript console.log().

Comment: @ArielFrischer ... then why in the world is this tagged bash, shell, and shell-script?

Comment: Because I wanted to catch it with bash script, and do it selectively for different fields. The output is in my bash terminal.